# Angular $injector:unpr with javascript file include order

Tags: angularjs

I have thee  angular service and one controller. And I'm including the files like this;

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="view/Product/productService.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="view/Invoice/invoiceService.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="view/Invoice/invoiceController.js"></script>
```

In this order I'm getting Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$injector/unpr?p0=ProductProvider%20%3C-%20Product%20%3C-%20invoiceController

But when I change to order to shown below, every thing is OK.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="view/Invoice/invoiceService.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="view/Product/productService.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="view/Invoice/invoiceController.js"></script>
```

There is no dependency in service files, but this error occurs depens on javascript files order. Here is files content

**productService.js**

```
angular.module('mainApp.services',[]).service('Product',function($resource){
    return $resource('http://localhost/invocy/api/public/product/:id', { id: '@id' }, {
        update: {
            method: 'PUT'
        }
    });
});
```

**invoiceService.js**

```
    angular.module('mainApp.services',[]).service('Invoice',function($resource){
    return $resource('http://localhost/invocy/api/public/invoice/:id', { id: '@id' }, {
        update: {
            method: 'PUT'
        }
    });
});
```

**invoiceController.js**

```
angular.module('mainApp.controllers', []).controller('invoiceController', function($scope,Product) {

        $scope.InvoiceProducts = [];
        $scope.sub_total=0;
        $scope.tax_total=0;
        $scope.AddProduct = function() {
            $scope.InvoiceProducts.push(
                {
                    name:'xxx',
                    quantity:1,
                    unit_price:0,
                    total:0
                }
            );
        };
        $scope.AddProduct();

        $scope.UpdateTotals=function(){
            angular.forEach(InvoiceProducts,function(key,InvoiceProduct){
                $scope.sub_total+=InvoiceProduct.total;
                $scope.tax_total=100;
            });
            $scope.general_total=$scope.sub_total+$scope.tax_total;
        };


        /* Ürün Arama */
        $scope.products=new Product();
        $scope.selectedNumber = null;

        // instantiate the bloodhound suggestion engine
        var numbers = new Bloodhound({
            datumTokenizer: function(d) { return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.num); },
            queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
            local: $scope.products.$query()
        });

        // initialize the bloodhound suggestion engine
        numbers.initialize();

        $scope.numbersDataset = {
            displayKey: 'num',
            source: numbers.ttAdapter()
        };

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
angular.module('mainApp.services',[])
```

This **defines** a module named 'mainApp.services'. If such a module has been defined before, then it overwrites it completely. So you should not use that in your service files. To get a reference to an already defined module, the syntax is

```
angular.module('mainApp.services')
```

without the array of dependencies as second argument.

Declare your modules in a separate file, included first, then add all your services and controllers to these modules.

Comment: After removing it I'm getting this error : Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$injector/nomod?p0=mainApp.services

Comment: Because, as I said, you need to define the module before, in a separate file, but only once.

Comment: I'm not sure, If I understand you correctly. I have created a definition like this : http://paste.ubuntu.com/14654047/ But still getting some errors. : Uncaught TypeError: angular.module(...).config(...).module is not a function

Comment: You need to define the services and controllers module: `angular.module('mainApp.services', []); angular.module('mainApp.controllers', []);`. You can't chain module definitions like you're doing. And you shouldn't define the Invoice and Product services there, but in their own file.

Comment: Working like a charm. Thank you @JB Nizet